# JOptionPane , Còmo setear por defecto el foco en el jtext cuando se abra el componente.?

Tags: java-swing

como se puede observar en la imagen al abrirse el joptionpane el foco aparece por defecto en el boton aceptar.

[image: Joptionpane]

Lo que se desea es que el foco este en el text para dar comodidad al usuario.

El código que se tiene es el siguiente.

```
JDateChooser jd = new JDateChooser(); 
jd.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
String message = " Por favor Ingrese la fecha del documento en la operación : \n " + cmbServicios.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n  Recuerde:   No puede ser mayor a la actual." 
Object[] params = {message, jd};
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, params, "INDEXACION ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: justo estoy buscando solucionar el mismo problema que planteas aquí. si has logrado solucionarlo, podrías compartirlo. gracias!

Comment: Saludos amigo, sabes que no encontre nada que permita cambiar el foco del boton

Answer (score 0):

podrías probar con esta opción:

```
JDateChooser jd = new JDateChooser(); 
jd.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Gracias Javier por tu respuesta , pero no soluciona sigue cargándose el foco en el botón aceptar.

Answer (score 0):

La solución a este inconveniente la encontré aquí https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/

básicamente es crear esta clase

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class RequestFocusListener implements AncestorListener
{
private boolean removeListener;

public RequestFocusListener()
{
    this(true);
}

public RequestFocusListener(boolean removeListener)
{
    this.removeListener = removeListener;
}

@Override
public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent e)
{
    JComponent component = e.getComponent();
    component.requestFocusInWindow();

    if (removeListener)
        component.removeAncestorListener( this );
}

@Override
public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent e) {}

@Override
public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent e) {}
}
```

y luego implementarla al componente por ejemplo quedaría así para este caso

```
JDateChooser jd = new JDateChooser();
jd.addAncestorListener( new RequestFocusListener() );
```